# using LAG and LAST.VAR for creating variables

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset:

```
AGE    HSQ    PCT

65      1     0.7
65      2     0.2
65      3     0.1
66      1     0.5
66      2     0.25
66      3     0.25

[...]
```

What I need is to get the followig output:

```
AGE     P1    P2     P3

65     0.7    0.2    0.1
66     0.5    0.25   0.25

[...]
```

I have been told to adopt `LAG` and `FIRST.AGE` or `LAST.AGE` in order to do that, and to me it seems a good strategy. However I am not able to get the final result.. the (wrong) code I am using is:

```
DATA OUTPUT;
  SET SAMPLE;
    BY AGE HSQ;
  IF LAST.AGE THEN DO;
    P1=LAG2(PCT);
    P2=LAG1(PCT);
    P3=PCT;
  END;
RUN;
```

But it jumps to previus ages percentages, which is not what I need.. where is the syntax error? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have been told as in this is an assignment to use them, or as in this is the easiest way to do it?

The easiest way to do this is PROC TRANSPOSE:

```
data have;
input AGE    HSQ    PCT;
datalines;
65      1     0.7
65      2     0.2
65      3     0.1
66      1     0.5
66      2     0.25
66      3     0.25
;;;;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want prefix=P;
by age;
var pct;
id hsq;
run;
```

LAG does not work the way you think it works - it does *not* give you the value of the previous row; it instead creates a queue and takes the current value of (argument) and gives you the previous value on the queue.  So you can't use it in an IF statement like that.

If you for some reason had to do this in a datastep, then you would want to do it like this:

```
data want;
array p[3];
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.age);
    set have;
    by age;
    p[hsq]=pct;
end;
keep p1-p3 age;
run;
```

Really no reason to use lag, or any concept of lag; just as you come across values that belong in a place, you assign them to that place, and when you hit last.age then output.

Anybody want to join me in putting in a SASware request to remove the LAG function?

Comment: Well, I just have to obtain the final result, hence the TRANSPOSE option seems much more elegant and less "error prone". After some research on the Internet, I agree that LAG is not the easier function to understand, especially for beginners.. thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I'm almost with you Joe!  Unfortunately there's a few rare cases where lag is useful.  For example - values from 2 rows ago (`lag2`), or 3 rows ago(`lag3`), etc.  And also, if you want to retain every value in a row then lag is probably easier.  Other than that I completely agree that it's a horribly overused function.  Unfortunately I think it's this way because the lag concept is so heavily used in stats.  If they fixed the lag functions so that it captured the values regardless of whether it was located in an `if` execution branch or not I think that would go a long way to redeeming it.

Comment: Just to clarify - my above comment is from the point of view of using it to capture data from previous rows, and not using it for it's intended purpose, which as you pointed out, is to provide queueing functionality.

Comment: If you want to get the values from two rows ago, then merge the dataset to itself, or use POINT (random access), or do any of the number of other things you can do to get that correctly.  LAG and LAGn are almost never the right answer when it comes to accessing other rows.  The correct 'fix' for LAG is to rename it QUEUE and stop people from thinking it is a function it is not...

Comment: +1 for mentioning the DOW-loop data step option. In my experience this is much faster than proc transpose, and scales better when you need to transpose multiple variables.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, the direct answer to the original question (to show how this could be done):

```
DATA want;
  SET have;
    BY AGE HSQ;
    p1=lag2(pct);
    p2=lag1(pct);
    p3=pct;
    if last.age then output;
run;
```

This goes over a lot of extra work (by a lot I mean a few nanoseconds of CPU time, of course) because it calculates the lags six times and only outputs two of the results.  It also is a bit 'risky' because it doesn't check to make sure HSQ is the correct value - ie, if you missed one entry for an age, and only had 2 rows for it, you'd have the previous age's HSQ=3 value for P1, which is probably not desired.

The ultimate point is that with LAG, if you do intend to use it as a stand-in for "previous row's record", you need to keep it outside of conditional blocks.  Calculate the lag for *every* row, and use the *result* conditionally (in this case, output is used conditionally).

Comment: Thanks again, this clears my last doubts about LAG. Missing values would definitely lead to a wrong output in this particular case.. for people interested here there is a pdf underlying your point about dealing with conditional blocks: http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nesug.org%2Fproceedings%2Fnesug06%2Fcc%2Fcc32.pdf&ei=85d1UNb2C-aA4gSLz4H4Dw&usg=AFQjCNHFPT8ZsNi7NyjajNFO2a0MSSpveg